# Calling an instance declared in one method from another method

Tags: c#, scope, instance

I have a bit of a rudimentary question. I have a total of two classes.

I have a few methods inside one class. The skeleton structure is so:

First class is called `EvenBetterValueList` (public):

```
public override void AppendAdditionalMenuItems(ToolStripDropDown menu){
    // Stuff
}

private void Menu_MyCustomItemClicked(object sender, EventArgs e){
    // Stuff
}

protected override void SolveInstance(IGH_DataAccess DA){
    // firstList and secondList list<string> declaration
    ValueList newList = new ValueList(firstList, secondList);
}
```

Second class is called `ValueList` (as you can tell in my SolveInstance method. This too is public):

The skeleton is:

```
    private List<string> _firstList = new List<string>();
    private List<string> _secondList = new List<string>();

    public List<string> FirstList 
    {
        get { return _firstList; }
    }

    public List<string> SecondList
    {
        get { return _secondList; }
    }

    public ValueList(List<string> firstList, List<string> secondList) {
        _firstList.Clear();
        _secondList.Clear();

        // Add vars to global vars

        _firstList.AddRange(firstList);
        _secondList.AddRange(secondList);
    }
```

My question is, in `SolveInstance` of the first class `EvenBetterValueList`, I am able to use the new instance `newList` that I've declared. However, I am unable to use this instance in the other methods, like `AppendAdditionalMenuItems()` or `Menu_MyCustomItemClicked()`.

I would like to access `newList` inside those two methods, and call things like `newList.FirstList[index]` or `newList.SecondList[index]`.

The way this abstract class works is that it always called `SolveInstance()` before anything, I feel this information is quite important.

Is this a scope issue? How do I solve it?

Comment: Please use AddRange if available, rather than calling Add in a loop... Or one of the many other available ways of combining lists...

Comment: That's not the question.. But do you mean `_firstList.AddRange(..)` versus `_firstList.Add(..)`? What's the difference?

Comment: When you add something to a collection, the collection's internal array may have to enlarge to fit the new element. If you do that in a loop, it may happen N times. If you do AddRange, it happens once, and you don't need a loop. You probably don't even need the ValueList class, since it doesn't add anything that normal Lists can't do with Linq.

Comment: I made the `ValueList` class so it's easier to read for future devs, and there are additional methods below. How do you use `.AddRange(..)` without a for-loop?

Comment: Magus could you also please tell me how I can solve my initial question?

Comment: `_firstList.AddRange(firstList);`, for instance. It adds all the values in firstList to _firstList, but you don't have to think about it. If it matters that the elements alternate from the two lists, you could try Linq's aggregate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution may be to add a private variable in the class with class scope. Add the line:

```
ValueList _valueList;
```

Just outside of the method and use that one instead of newList within your methods.

Read more about scopes
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691132(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: Hey Lars. When I declare my `_valueList` using: `ValueList _valueList = new ValueList(firstList, secondList);`, I get this warning: http://puu.sh/6CHP1/361f7a8552.png I also included the `SolveInstance()` where I create the new instance.

Comment: It is becouse you create a new instance in your method right now. On the row where you say ValueList _valueList = new ValueList... you are not using the class scoped variable. You are creating a new variable in the method. Remove the class name infront of the local variable will make the code use the class variable instead.

Answer (score 1):

The problem that you're having is that newList is defined only within your SolveInstance method, meaning that you were correct about it being a scoping issue. Declare it as a private field, and it will be available. I'd also consider changing SolveInstance into the constructor if the method is indeed always called before anything else.

Comment: Do you mean declaring `SolveInstance()` as a private field? There is no need to turn `SolveInstance()` into a constructor as `public class EvenBetterValueList : GH_Component` does all the work of determining what gets executed first.

Comment: **If** as you stated above `SolveInstance()` is *always* called before any other method, why force users to remember that? That's what constructors are for. Including more detail in your comments that isn't visible in your post to invalidate comments, criticism, and advice helps no one, particularly you. If the domain of your problem is important, leaving it out *will not* get you an answer you can use.

Comment: It's actually an abstract class I'm using - I'm coding up an application for Grasshopper 3D. Not much I can do inside those confines =P.

Comment: Hey Magus.. I know you answered first, but Lars provided the code snippet, so I accepted his answer. No hard feelings?